# Unity3D Run Time Error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

At the moment I've set up a dual camera scene in Unity. I've created an empty game object for my camera's to inherit from and attached some of the first person controller scripts to this empty game object.

When I run the program in the editor, it runs fine. When I build the project, the game crashes and my camera objects fall through the ground. I've never experienced something like this before in Unity. Attached is a copy of my my current fps set up values.

In the picture, you will see that I have turned gravity off (set it to 0), yet it still falls down when I run the built program.

[image]

Has anyone ever come across something like this before? I've spent all day trying to fix this, but I'm getting no where.

Comment: Is there an error message that's shown when your game crashes? How does it crash? Is the crash always the same?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced such an issue when my parent object (I usually use capsules to "carry" the camera as the players head like 1.70m above the ground) is set to low ... what happens if you move your camera-guy together with the game object one meter upwards? (so that he falls down a bit against the surface when you start).

Maybe there is a difference in some relations between editor-build and release-build.

Or, in case this isn't the solution, check the spatial positions of your involved objects again. Falling through a terrain is often produced by misplaced reference objects. (I sometimes hung a *carrier object under a camera* instead of hanging the *camera under a carrier object*.)

As you say that it works in the editor-build i assume that you have activated *collision* for the relevant objects.